# IBM bluemixでphp.iniを変更する方法

Tags: php, bluemix, phpmyadmin

IBM bluemixに下記のgitを利用してphpmyadminをインストールしようとしていますが、
php.iniのmax_file_uploads値を変更するにはどのようにすればよいのでしょうか。

https://github.com/dmikusa-pivotal/cf-ex-phpmyadmin

なにかよい方法がありましたらご教示いただけると大変助かります。よろしくお願いします。

ちなみに、manifest.ymlを参照するとPHPは以下のbuildpackよりインストールする仕様のようです。

buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack.git#8c13f5434b2f31ca960d2bca9153df1978258535

Comment: せめてマルチポストであることを明記してください。マナー違反です。
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=e1e35933-016a-4230-b198-9bfe7650d38c

Comment: こちらも
https://teratail.com/questions/16639

Answer (score 1):

この Buildpack で試したわけではないのですが、php.ini の環境変数は ini_set() 関数で変更することができる場合があります。

ini_set での変更が許可されていない場合は Buildpack 側で php.ini を設定する必要があるので、目的にあった環境の Buildpack を独自に用意した上で指定してランタイムとして使う、という必要があると思われます。

Answer (score 1):

このBuildpackのドキュメント [HTTPD, Nginx and PHP configuration](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack/blob/master/docs/config.md#httpd-nginx-and-php-configuration) に従うのであれば、php5.5系の場合は`.bp-config/config/php/5.5.x/php.ini`を作成して設定を変更できるはずです。